# Firefox and Chrome won't decode base64 image or pdf files

Tags: html, image, firefox, google-chrome, base64

I'm trying to decode a base64 encoded images on the browser by using the data uri scheme.

This is what my html looks like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,base64_string_here" 
  alt="base64 image name" width="600" height="400" border="1" />
```

Chrome and Firefox are unable to decode these images and display the default "image can't load" image instead. I've verified that the base64 images I'm passing to the browser are correct. In fact Safari has no problems displaying the same images.

I tried getting the browsers to decode similar base64 encoded pdfs instead, but this did not work either. (Again, it didn't work on Chrome and Firefox but worked on Safari.)

```
<img src="data:application/pdf;base64,base64_string_here" 
  alt="base64 pdf name" width="600" height="400" border="1" />
```

Chrome version: 18.0, FF version: 11.0

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? (If it helps at all- the base64 encoded images I'm trying to display are USPS shipping labels).

Comment: Can you post one complete example with base64 data?

Comment: Have you verified that Firefox can open the original image?

Comment: Here's a link to the base64 data: http://pastebin.com/KGvQUDYN

Comment: @Anonymous There is no "original" image- the response I get is from USPS's server. This response is a base64 encoded string, and needs to be displayed on a browser as an image. I don't have a deep understanding of base64, but when I use an online decoder (opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Decode/), I'm able to open the binary it returns only in Safari (after changing its extension to .jpg) . Firefox and Chrome are unable to open this file. Does that information help?

Comment: Found some more useful information:
The image that I was getting back from USPS was a TIF. Google Chrome and Firefox both don't open TIF files. That explains why they were unable to decode the base64 image files. 
But I am also able to get pdf's from USPS instead of TIF's. Google Chrome should be able to open pdf's but from what I'm seeing, its unable to decode them when they're in base64 encoding. However, Chrome is able to open the pdf after I decode it first. 
(Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)

Comment: if you change it to `image/tif` it works

Comment: i also have this problem, the same file can be render in IE & Edge, but can no be showing in chrome. i don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question but I have recently ran into the same issue. (Stemming from USPS label returns) I fixed it by converting the Base64 string encoded TIFF to a Base64 string Bitmap image (though you could use any image type that you wish).

I was using C# to convert the images:

```
    Byte[] arrTiff = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(oeVS.LabelImage));
    System.IO.MemoryStream msTiff = new System.IO.MemoryStream(arrTiff);
    Bitmap bmpTiff = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(msTiff));
    System.IO.MemoryStream msBmp = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    bmpTiff.Save(msBmp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    Byte[] arrBmp = msBmp.ToArray();
    string sBMP64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arrBmp);
```

Then in the html/javascript you can use this to display the label where sBMP64 is the result from above.

`<img src='data:image/bmp;base64,sBMP64'>`

BMP worked for my purposes, but here's a table of image support by browser: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox can, very likely, open TIF images -- if you tell them, they are TIF images. Currently in your example you are telling them, they are PNG images, which ought to be the problem... Try:

```
<img src="data:image/tiff;base64,base64_string_here" 
  alt="base64 image name" width="600" height="400" border="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, even if you supply correct MIME type, Chrome, Firefox and Opera do not support .TIF files natively: they require a plugin to deal with them.

There's a useful summary of browser support for image files here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Comment: This seems to claim that Google Chrome supports pdfs in the img tag. But If I try <img src=test.pdf> the image doesn't show up (though it does in e.g. Safari).

Answer (score 0):

it has something to do with recent Chromium team's decision to block Top-frame navigations to data URLs (in Google Chrome latest version 60 update).

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/wvYYcBwJ9FA;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3AStable%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false

Comment: That seems unlikely, considering that the OP was experiencing this problem while using Chrome 18 in 2012.