# Chrome Not Showing String Base64 Image

Tags: asp.net, image, google-chrome

I am trying to display an asp.net Image using a Base64 String.  It works in Explorer but not in Chrome.

Here is the code:

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
```

http://juanpado.brinkster.net/pagina1.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox and Chrome won't decode base64 image or pdf files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936239/firefox-and-chrome-wont-decode-base64-image-or-pdf-files)

Comment: And [Display TIFF image in all web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser).

Comment: Thanks Werner.  
I review the image format and they were saved in database as blob indicating jpg format.

Comment: Could you check the image example I published in the URL: http://juanpado.brinkster.net/pagina1.html?

Comment: No, that's a TIFF. The first two bytes are "MM", where a JPEG would be "JFIF" or "Exif" in the first few bytes.